# Cannot add CAGradientLayer to show up in UIView subclass

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ios8, quartz-core

I have this UIView subclass I want to use for displaying a custom view. The problem is I cann't make the custom `CAGradientLayer` to show up in my view... I still see it as a red stripe.

```
public class PSTLoadingBar : UIView {

private var loadingBarView: UIView!
private var gradientLayer: CAGradientLayer!

required public init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("Not coder compliant")
}

public override var frame: CGRect {
    didSet {

        if frame == CGRect.zeroRect {
            return
        }

        loadingBarView.frame = frame
    }
}

// MARK: - Singleton
public class var sharedInstance: PSTLoadingBar {
    struct Singleton {
        static let instance = PSTLoadingBar(frame: CGRect.zeroRect)
    }
    return Singleton.instance
}

public override init(frame:CGRect) {

    super.init(frame:frame)

    loadingBarView = UIView()
    loadingBarView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()

    gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    gradientLayer.frame = loadingBarView.bounds
    gradientLayer.opacity = 1

    let color1 = UIColor(red: 67/255, green: 36/255, blue: 84/255, alpha: 1).CGColor
    let color2 = UIColor(red: 67/255, green: 36/255, blue: 84/255, alpha: 1).CGColor

    let colors = [color1, color2]

    gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPointMake(0,0.5)
    gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPointMake(1.0, 0.5)
    gradientLayer.colors = colors


    loadingBarView.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, atIndex:0)

    addSubview(loadingBarView)

}

// MARK: - Public Methods
public class func show(parentView: UIView) {

    let loadingBar = PSTLoadingBar.sharedInstance

    let _view = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController?.view

    if let _view = _view {

        loadingBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 32, _view.bounds.width, 5)


        if loadingBar.superview == nil {
            _view.addSubview(loadingBar)
        }

    }
}
```

I've tried adding the sublayer in various indexes and I've also tried with `self.layer` instead of `loadingBar.layer` but again with no success.

I am suspecting I need to override another method from UIView but I am not really sure if that's the case.

Any ideas?

Comment: Your colours are identical, so you're not going to see a gradient...

Comment: @IanMacDonald this is irrelevant. I am not seeing anythingthing close to the colors, I am seeing red which is the UIView's `backgroundColor`. I am not seeing any gradient even if I set two different colors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you create `loadingBarView`, its frame is CGRectZero—a rectangle with zero width and height—which causes the gradient layer to similarly have zero width and height and therefore not appear. Adding the layer in `-layoutSubviews` isn’t necessary — you just need to update its frame to `loadingBarView`’s bounds there.